# Installing plugins in fresh Craft4 install causes error of identifying as older plugin version

Tags: plugin-feedme, plugin-supertable, craft4

I tried upgrading to Craft 4 (4.2.5.1), and Feed Me and Super Table would not upgrade properly, causing Craft to crash. When installing the compatible versions, old version numbers populate in the db, causing this error: “You need to be on at least Feed Me 4.4.2 before you can update to Feed Me 5.0.4.”

I ended up trying a completely new Craft install and DB, and ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue on a website which has been upgraded to CraftCMS 4 but forgot to upgrade Feed Me at the time as it was disabled and not used.
When I then needed to use Feed Me again I went to try and enabled but got the above error.
I had to manually remove any trace of the feedme plugin from the database - deleted the 3 tables related to it and the row relating to it in the plugins table.
It was also removed from composer.json etc.
After that I tried to install it from the Plugin Store and it worked fine.